# comparison between three parameters

Tags: python, string, function, boolean, output

I have a function in python which says I gotta take in 3 parameters and the word has to be in the hand and the word also has to be in the wordlist

```
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
    d = hand.copy()
    for c in word:
        d[c] = d.get(c, 0) - 1
        if d[c] < 0 or word not in wordList:
            return False
    return sum(d.itervalues()) == 0
```

it works perfectly in 12 outta 14 test cases -

```
Function call: isValidWord(hammer, {'a': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'm': 2, 'e': 1}, <edX internal wordList>)

Output:
True
```

but in other cases its wrong!

```
Random Test 1
Function call: isValidWord(shrimp, {'e': 1, 'i': 1, 'h': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'n': 1, 'p': 1, 's': 1, 'r': 1, 'y': 1}, <edX internal wordList>)
Your output:
False
Correct output:
True

Random Test 5
Function call: isValidWord(carrot, {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1, 's': 1, 'r': 2, 't': 1, 'x': 1}, <edX internal wordList>)
Your output:
False
Correct output:
True

Random Test 7
Function call: isValidWord(shoe, {'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'h': 1, 'o': 1, 's': 1, 'w': 1, 'y': 2}, <edX internal wordList>)
Your output:
False
Correct output:
True
```

now why is this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is excluding "hands" that contain the word's letters *and* extra letters. For example, `f('tree', {'t': 1, 'r': 1, 'e': 2, 's': 1})` (`'trees'`) should return `True`, as that "hand" contains all of the letters necessary to make `'tree'`.

You don't need to check for them:

```
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordlist):
    if word not in wordlist:
        return False

    for letter in word:
        if letter not in hand:
            return False

        hand[letter] -= 1

        if hand[letter] < 0:
            return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
    return word in wordList and all(hand.get(a, 0) >= b for a, b in getFrequencyDict(word).items())
```

try this it would give correct response